# What was the longest time it took to assemble a coalitional government?

Tags: history, coalition

In democratic countries with party-list voting systems, parties usually do not have an absolute majority, and have to form coalitions with other parties. It may happen that no party manages to assemble a coalition, and in this case, usually the elections should be repeated. In Israel, in the last two years, there were several repeat-elections due to failure in assembling a government.

My question is: what are some recent events in other countries, in which it took an exceptionally long time (and possibly several repeated elections) to assemble a coalitional government?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Belgium has gone the longest time without a federal government in peacetime, [592 days*](https://www.brusselstimes.com/belgium/124777/belgium-breaks-own-record-for-longest-period-without-government)  without a government following the election in May 2019.

* counted from the collapse of the Michel coalition in December 2018

Belgium has also been [541 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010%E2%80%932011_Belgian_government_formation) without a government following the election in June 2010.

Comment: I'm not sure if the first count is fair. Now it's counted since the collapse of the previous government, while the question asks about the time it took to form a government. On the other end of the period, that article preceded the forming of a new government. It took two more months before [the new government gained the confidence of the chamber on October 3rd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%932020_Belgian_government_formation#Coformationists_Alexander_De_Croo_and_Paul_Magnette_(23_September_2020_-_1_October_2020)).

Comment: @JJJ regardless whether it answers the question, it's a Guiness World Record and the Belgians held multiple street parades, when it occured, in celebration of this fact. I always found this amusing :)

Answer (score 12):

Northern Ireland had no devolved government for a total of 1,097 days after Deputy First Minister Martin McGuinness resigned on January 9th, 2017 in response to the [Renewable Heat Incentive scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewable_Heat_Incentive_scandal). This period ended when the Northern Ireland Assembly resumed on January 11th, 2020 after [talks between party leaders & Julian Smith](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-50801484), then-Secretary of State for Northern Ireland led to the [New Decade, New Approach](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/856998/2020-01-08_a_new_decade__a_new_approach.pdf) agreement.

However, Northern Ireland still had a government in the sense that the UK government in Westminster remained in place.

Comment: I would interpret the question as referring to independent countries. Otherwise one would have to check individual states and provinces in various other countries as well.

Comment: @quarague technically Northern Ireland is a country within the United Kingdom. But that's nitpicking :)